# How to call functions defined in parent document from an svg referenced by an <object> element?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I used  to embed an svg file to my webpage:

```
    <object id="svgmap" width="100%" height="100%" data="<%=path %>/svg/map.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="">
    </object>
```

and then I added some images tags into this svg file using an external javascript file called "support.js":

```
    var marker = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'image');
    marker.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', "img_0123");
    marker.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', iconurl);
    marker.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', posX);
    marker.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', posY);
    marker.setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'visible');
    marker.setAttribute("onclick", "onsel('0123')");
```

This "onsel" function is defined in support.js as well, so when I clicked on the image, it changes to another image. Now when i viewed this page in browsers (Opera, Mozilla and Chrome), it didn't swap to another image when i clicked on the image, and in the developer tool's console, it said "referenceerror: onsel is not defined                                  svgmap:1".

Does that mean the svg files cannot use functions defined in other javascript files? How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've interpreted your question as "how do I call functions defined in the scope of a parent html document from an svg referenced by an <object> element?". It's a little unclear from the question where your "onsel" function is defined, but I'm guessing it's in a script inside the html document.

Here's an [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/from-svg-to-parent-html-script.html) of how to call from inside the svg out to the parent. The function in the parent prints what element was clicked and which element it was referenced from.

From svg to parent document:

```
    window.parent.yourFunctionInParentDocument();
```

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for! Thanks a lot!